# I cannot get my CSS code to show the changes I am making in the browser

Tags: html, css

I cannot get my CSS code to show the changes I am making in the browser when I refresh it.  Some of the CSS code is working correctly and some of the CSS code I provided below is not working correctly.  I am trying to change the CSS on my main header navigation bar and none of the changes are working.  For example, if I change the background color to red nothing happens.

```css
   nav {
 width: 100%; 
   height: 100px; 
   background-color: #0b98de;
    }

    nav a {
 display: block; 
 font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 9px;
    color: white;
 background-color: #17b0cf;
    border: 1px solid #000;
 padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
    }

    nav a:hover {
    background-color:#e3e7ee
    }

    #logo {
    font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #c4c4c4;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
 <nav>
 <a id="logo" href="#">Logo</a>
 <a href="#">How it works</a>
 <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
 <a href="#">Login</a>
    </nav>
   </body>
```

Comment: It is working check this.. https://jsfiddle.net/qLwvy57z/

Comment: created a code snippet of your code and added a css `background-color:#e3e7ee` on hover and it is working. can you please explain what is not working?

Comment: @bender1227 Modify your question title and be clear what your problem is.

Make the question clear and breif your problem in the body.

your code wrks fine for me


Try hard refreshing your page in browser. There may be cache issues while trying to change css styles.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code structure fo HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
        nav {
            width: 100%; 
            height: 100px; 
            background-color: #0b98de;
        }

        nav a {
            display: block; 
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 9px;
            color: white;
            background-color: #17b0cf;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        nav a:hover {}

        #logo {
            font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
            font-size: 30px;
            letter-spacing: -2px;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #c4c4c4;
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 40px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-top: -20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a id="logo" href="#">Logo</a>
        <a href="#">How it works</a>
        <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
        <a href="#">Login</a>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if I don't want my styling to be incline with the HTML code but rather in an external style sheet will this still work?

Comment: code-only answers aren't answers IMO, they should explain the issue and solution

Answer (score -1):

Make sure of your HTML syntax and create a **style.css** file and insert your css code there. It'll be a good practice.

1. Maintain a separate `style.css` file or use `<style>` tag inside your html file.
2. Always follow correct patters while creating `navbar` first `ul` and then `li`.

```css
nav {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: #0b98de;
}

nav a {
    display: block; 
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #17b0cf;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color:grey;
}

#logo {
    font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #c4c4c4;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a id="logo" href="#">Logo</a>
        <a href="#">How it works</a>
        <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
        <a href="#">Login</a>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: code-only answers aren't answers IMO, they should explain the issue and solution

Comment: also as a note, tis better practice to use `<ul>` and `<li>` as nav elements

Comment: hey @treyBake !! apologies from my side. Since this a code snippet solution, i had to answer only code. I'll edit my answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You have a syntax error in your

```
nav a:hover{
    background-color:#e3e7ee      
}
```

You ought to end things with a semi-colon in CSS. change the following to

```
nav a:hover{
    background-color:#e3e7ee;
}
```

If it still doesn't work, try using a different browser and see how it behaves. If it works in a different browser, you will have to clear the cache of your testing browser.

Comment: as a note: if the property is the last (or only) in the list, it doesn't need a semi-colon